# Setting ImageView width dynamically in a Xamarin Android project

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, android-mvvm

I am trying to dynamically set the ImageView height in Xamarin droid project not in core.

```
LinearLayout layout4 = new LinearLayout(Activity);
layout4.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
layout4.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center);
layout4.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
```

---

**I am not able to set:**

```
layout4.Height = 20;
```

**Getting error:** Property or indexer cannot be assigned, it is read only

Answer (score 0):

Use LayoutParams:

```
LinearLayout layout4 = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams parameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(currentWidth, 20/*desired height*/);
layout4.LayoutParameters = parameters;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the same as Java the **height** field of the `LinearLayout` is not accesible through the instance but with the LayoutParams.

You can set the desired height when creating the `LayoutParams` instance.

```
layout4.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, 20);
```

But, if you want to modify this value after the `LayoutParams` has been created and set you can do it like this:

```
layout4.LayoutParameters.Height = 20;
```